# Progressbar not stopping

Tags: android, progress-bar

I made a progress bar to run for 5 second.it showing perfectly for first time.but for second time it not stopping after 5 second.it keeps running.
Code is here

```
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
     switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Finding Nearest Officer...");
            pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            //pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();


            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    //delayInMillis=5000;
                }
            }, 5000);
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return pDialog;
     }
 }
```

Comment: after restarting the app it again working for first time.but not for second time.

Comment: you sure second time the input is `progress_bar_type` if not then `default` will not trigger any timertask

Comment: please describe

Comment: i can't see your full that what is happening when the input is not  `progress_bar_type` so paste your full code but the clear idea is , your `default` case is getting executed and no `timertask` is there to dismiss dialog , try copy paste your timertask code in default code too

Comment: yes i did.but still same problem

Comment: even i removed the switch case. it still same problem

Comment: is your pDialog final variable?

Comment: There is problem in another place of code. your this method is working properly. I try it in my code. when I call this method It behave same everytime (take 5 sec progress than stop). can you please put here code of you call this method?

Comment: what do you mean by second time? is it a loop or what?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need another callback method to be overriden

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    // perform scheduling for dismiss here
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
}
```

In other words - `onCreateDialog()` is being called only first time, but `onPrepareDialog` is being called each time before you going to show it, so all your scheduling is better to setup inside `onPrepareDialog()`.

Also it is important to notice that all these APIs are deprecated and it is better to take a look at [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you make object from this method like this:

```
Dialog dialog = onCreateDialog(progress_bar_type);
```

And call Dialog by that aboject like this:

```
dialog.show();
```

but instead of that please call only method where you want that dialog to show.
like this:

```
onCreateDialog(progress_bar_type);
```

when ever you want to show dialog please only call this method directly.
you will get same output every time.